# AWS Lambda missing events from S3 to SQS

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have S3 Create Object -> SQS -> Lambda. In most cases it works (less than 100 new objects). When there are 1K+ objects created in S3, about 10% events do not make it to SQS. We have lambda logging all events as a first step in the function (Java) but these events never show up!

AWS Lambda is configured as Batch Size 10 and Batch Window 10.

Visibility Timeout in both the trigger and sqs is 30 minutes. each event processing in lambda takes 35seconds. Is there any other sqs/trigger/lambda settings I need to configure to not loose events? it doesn't matter if the processing takes many hours.

```
public String handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) {
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
    logger.log("\rProcessing Event: " + sqsEvent.toString());
    sqsEvent.getRecords().stream().forEach(
            sqsRecord -> {
                S3EventNotification s3EventNotification = S3EventNotification.parseJson(sqsRecord.getBody());
                logger.log("\rReceived S3EventRecords: " + s3EventNotification.getRecords().size());
                s3EventNotification.getRecords().forEach(
                        s3Record -> {
                            logger.log("\rProcessing s3: " + s3Record.getS3());
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the Lambda function is logging all the SQS messages it is receiving, since you have it configured to receive up to 10 with each invocation?

Comment: yes, added code in original question. Also, I added additional info about visibility timeout

Comment: What "original question"? I don't see any code in your question.

Comment: just updated with additional info.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean SQS is missing 10% of the S3 objects created and Lambda works as expected by logging 100% of whatever is available on SQS queues?

Comment: It could be sqs not getting it or messages removed/expired before picked up by lambda. The end  result is that the first log line does not exist for the 10% of events/objects that were missing. My suspicion is the latter but it is hard to calculate how long to hold messages (visibility timeout) since we don't know how many instances of lambda is at work! Or atleast I am trying to find a way to debug this.

Comment: Is it a regular SQS queue or a FIFO queue?

Comment: Regular sqs queue

Comment: I think the best bet is to make sure whether SQS is queueing up all messages or not. I would advise you to purge the queue, throttle the lambda to zero and fire 1K object creation on S3. See if SQS will queue up accordingly. Important to remember that because of scale aspects of a standard SQS, messages might duplicate, therefore you should get 1K or more messages pending in the queue. Is it possible to make this test?

Answer (score 1):

This is what AWS says.
'Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer'. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html

You may also want to look into the cloudwatch to ensure that all the events have been received in SQS.

[SQS Cloudwatch Monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00syX.png)

The next step you may want to check is for throttling in Lambda. This also might result in lost events. You may try adjusting the lambda concurrency with a desired value.

Comment: If it takes longer time for >15k (12+ hours) it is still acceptable. But, if there are missing events, its is useless. I am looking for a fool proof settings for message visibility timeout and batch size given each message can take upto 45 seconds of lambda processing.